# App deployed but not working with Ingress Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, docker-desktop

I am trying to deploy the .Net app using the Kubernetes using docker desktop.I want to run the app using the ingress. I use the below yaml file. When u create the deployment everything created successfully and everything created deployment,service, ingress but app is not opening on browser.

Note: when i bypass the ingress and only use service , my applications works fine with service but not working with ingress.Need help on it.

### apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: netapp
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app: netapp
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: netapp
spec:
containers:
- name: netapp
image: dockerId/Imagename:latest
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
ports:
- containerPort: 80
protocol: TCP
resources:
limits:
memory: 512Mi
cpu: "1"
requests:
memory: 256Mi
cpu: "0.2"

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: netapp
spec:
ports:
- port: 6789
protocol: TCP
targetPort: 80
selector:
app: netapp-pod
type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: netapp
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
rules:
- host: localhost
http:
paths:
- path: /
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: netapp
port:
number: 6789

Comment: In ingress I see `host: localhost`, is that correct? I guess it should be the FQDN of your service?

Comment: i even use the fully qualify domain name and map it in host file